# Android Google Play Subscription gets canceled after buying it

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, react-native, in-app-subscription

I have a react native app and using [react-native-iap](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap) library to communicate with Apple/Google server to buy the subscriptions. The subscription got successful and it returns a transaction as well but when I try to use that receipt to validate in [in-app-purchase](https://github.com/voltrue2/in-app-purchase) library, it returns with cancelReason: 1. I don't know what's happening but as per the Google Play cancelReason:1 means, "Subscription was canceled by the system, for example because of a billing problem"

Below is the real purchase I tried with my app. I have added the amount to buy it from the prod app which uploaded on internal testing. This library isn't able to verify it. Even it's showing me as an active subscription on the Play store app in Manage Subscription.

If I try to restore purchase in my app, it would return a purchase but when I went to verify it from the in-app-purchase library, it doesn't validate. Don't know why.

Here is the receipt data I got from the react-native-iap library.

> {"purchaseToken":"sdfdsfssfsd.AE-Jw-8fCifXt8xC1LzUDMhl2EyupYjgdGjmkpdHZH-j3-0YWE4UGa_jFlKTwodhLbKXCIWg","productId":"com.xyz.subscription","acknowledged":true,"orderId":"GPA.31-25-01-22058","purchaseTime":1620884406333,"packageName":"com.xyz","purchaseState":0,"autoRenewing":true,"subscription":true}

The response I got from the in-app-purchase library -

> {"service":"google","status":0,"packageName":"com.xyz","productId":"com.xyz.subscription","purchaseToken":"sdfdsfssfsd.AE-Jw-8fCifXt8xC1LzUDMhl2EyupYjgdGjmkpdHZH-j3-0YWE4UGa_jFlKTwodhLbKXCIWg","startTimeMillis":"1620884406333","expiryTimeMillis":"1623562757349","autoRenewing":false,"priceCurrencyCode":"INR","priceAmountMicros":"79000000","countryCode":"IN","developerPayload":"","paymentState":1,"cancelReason":1,"orderId":"GPA.31-25-01-22058","acknowledgementState":1,"kind":"androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase"}

if it got canceled as per the response, I didn't get any refund in my account.

Please help :(

Comment: It's because of this change of Google play https://tech.hindustantimes.com/tech/news/google-play-to-pause-auto-renewing-subscriptions-free-trials-in-india-report-71619875378816.html

Google system itself failed the transaction.